# How to sort case-insensitive?

Tags: sort

Vim has `:sort` command, which sorts using case-sensitive by default. I would like to sort several lines using case-insensitive. I tried using `:isort`, however this command is not defined.

**Edit**: I have found the solution in `:help sort`, the command is `:sort i`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`:sort i` - sorts case-insensitive.